# $3\times3$ matrix inversion proof

Tags: matrices, proof-writing, inverse

$A = \begin{bmatrix} a & b & c \\ d & e  & f \\ g & h & i \end{bmatrix}$,
As $A^{-1} \times A = I$, $\begin{bmatrix} x_{11} & x_{12 }&x_{13} \\ x_{21} & x_{22 }&x_{23} \\ x_{31} & x_{32 }&x_{33} \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} a & b & c \\ d & e  & f \\ g & h & i \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$

From this we can see that:
$ax_{11}+dx_{12}+gx_{13}=1$, $ax_{21}+dx_{22}+gx_{23}=0$, 
$ax_{31}+dx_{32}+gx_{33}=0$
$bx_{11}+ex_{12}+hx_{13}=0$, $bx_{21}+ex_{22}+hx_{23}=1$, 
$bx_{31}+ex_{32}+hx_{33}=0$
$cx_{11}+fx_{12}+ix_{13}=0$, $cx_{21}+fx_{22}+ix_{23}=0$, 
$cx_{31}+fx_{32}+ix_{33}=1$
$\det A = a(ei-fh)-b(di-fg)+c(dh-eg)$

Using the above, can we prove a formula matrix for inverting 3x3 matrices?

Comment: Prove what formula? Or you want to find a formula?

Comment: Sorry, not prove, find. Its just finding a matrix of minors, then cofactors, then transposing and multiplying by 1/detA takes ages, so i was trying to minimise this time by using alt methods, I didnt know how to word it so search engines became useless ahaha

Comment: There are no simpler formulas then the matrix of minors. There is, however, a simple algorithm for finding inverse: [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination#Finding_the_inverse_of_a_matrix).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray*}
A = \begin{bmatrix} a & b & c \\ d & e  & f \\ g & h & i \end{bmatrix}
\end{eqnarray*}
Assuming $aei-afh+bfg-bdi+cdh-ceg \neq 0$
\begin{eqnarray*}
A^{-1} =\frac{1}{aei-afh+bfg-bdi+cdh-ceg} \begin{bmatrix} ei-fh & ch-bi & bf-ce \\ fg-di & ai-cg  & cd-af \\ dh-eg & bg-ah & ae-bd \end{bmatrix}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

Sure. If we solve that system of $9$ linear equations, we'll get a formula for the inverse of a $3\times3$ matrix. In fact, what we'll get is that the inverse if $A$ is $\frac1{\det A}$ times [this matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix#3_.C3.97_3_generic_matrix).